# local host, port number, and TCP/IP & UDP

Tags: network-programming, udp, tcp

I am trying to program a script to interface two applications, so I need to understand a few basic concepts, if someone could please help me grasp them:

When an application's manual says: This app listens to `localhost:9763`, it means it receives live data from the same machine on port number `9763`. Is this correct?

So, if an application's manual says: `Listen on UDP port 6004`, it means I have to specify `localhost:6004` similar to the first point?

Or does the first point (`localhost:9763`) imply that `TCP/IP` is being used, but the second point is on `UDP`?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if an app says it is listening on a particular port and doesn't specify TCP or UDP, that usually means TCP.  If you're not sure, you can probably figure it out based on what that particular app does and how it does it.

Comment: Also, 'listening on Xxx port YYY' in most cases means 'any:YYY' where 'any' means any interface, not only localhost.